# Download epub Book Programmatically and save in Documents Directory in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5, xcode4.2

I would like download an epub book and save it to my directory, then open the book in a webview. I know how to open a book in webview, I do not know how to download the epub book and save it to my Documents. I have tried unzipping the link that I have but whatever link I give I only can see the help.epub book only. I am unable to see the epub book which I needed in my documents.
 The code for unzipping is :

```
(void)unzipAndSaveFile{

    ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    NSLog(@"url%@",receivedUrl);
    NSLog(@"recieved%@",receivedTitle);
   if( [za UnzipOpenFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:receivedTitle ofType:@"epub"]] ){

    NSString *strPath=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/UnzippedEpub",[self applicationDocumentsDirectory]];
    //Delete all the previous files
            NSFileManager *filemanager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
            if ([filemanager fileExistsAtPath:strPath]) {
                NSError *error;
                [filemanager removeItemAtPath:strPath error:&error];
            }
            [filemanager release];
            filemanager=nil;

    //start unzip
    [za UnzipFileTo:strPath overWrite:YES];
    NSLog(@"path%@",strPath);
        }                   
    [za release];
}
```

I have parsed the data using JSON.

Comment: pathForResource:receivedTitle--- here in "receiveTitle" i am passing the epub link. please help me to sort out this problem...

Answer (score 0):

To unzip, you first need the epub file in your local iOS storage, so as far as I know, you can not do it directly via URL.

So, first download it, save it (e.g. in the documents directory) and then call your code above with pathForResource being the path to your .epub file in the documents directory.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: Thank u for the reply, I am able store the epub directly but whenever i am going to check that i am only able to see the help.epub and unable to find the other epub

Comment: Please let me how to download and save .epub file